# When testing an iOS app, why not all of the app crashes get reported?

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

I have about 8 testflight internal testers for an app I'm developing, for crash reporting we are using [Crittercism](https://app.crittercism.com/developers/login), some people see crashes that don't get reported to crittercism, why is that? how do I guarntee that all crashes get reported?

and if we read in this article in apple's documentation

> However, crash logs are not sent to Apple unless the user agrees to
>   share crash data with app developers. TestFlight users automatically
>   agree to share crash data. The service does the following to generate
>   crash reports:

any hints ?

Comment: I don't use Crittercism, but I do use Crashlytics by Fabric.io. I was having a similar problem with Crashlytics. After getting with their support team, it turns out that the crash reports were sent to us only on the next app launch on the device where the app crashed. Could it by that Crittercism has something similar? The app crashed and the users didn't open the app back up, and hence, it was never reported?

Comment: I read something like this on Crittercism's website, but I think there is a reason other than this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimentation, it looks like Firebase reports crashes in a way much better than Crittercism, and catches them all and provides better details.

and to quote bajracharyas353 :-

> "crash reports were sent to us only on the next app launch on the
>   device where the app crashed."